# Clerk Expo SDK throws "first_name is not a valid parameter for this request" on user.update()

Tags: react-native, expo, clerk

I'm trying to update user's firstName from ReactNavite app using @clerk/clerk-expo SDK:

```
  const { user } = useUser();

  const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState(user?.firstName ? user.firstName : "");

  const onUpdatePress = async () => {
    try {
      await user?.update({ firstName: firstName });
    } catch (err: any) {
      setErrorMessage(err.errors[0].longMessage);
      console.error(JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    }
  };
```

But it throws error:

```
 ERROR  {
  "status": 422,
  "clerkError": true,
  "errors": [
    {
      "code": "form_param_unknown",
      "message": "is unknown",
      "longMessage": "first_name is not a valid parameter for this request.",
      "meta": {
        "paramName": "first_name"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Is it a bug or I'm doing something wrong?

Used versions:

- react: 18.2.0
- react-native: 0.71.6
- expo: ~48.0.11
- @clerk/clerk-expo: ^0.18.16

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to enable the `Users can set their first and last name` option to set those properties. This option is disabled by default. You can find that on the `Email, Phone, Username` page under the `User & Authentication` section.

[image]

From there, scroll down to the `Personal Information` section and make sure the checkbox is enabled.

[image]